# How can I use an array value to build a reference to Settings?

Tags: c#

Say I have some values in my program's Settings file

```
ClassLibrary.Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName1
ClassLibrary.Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName2
ClassLibrary.Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName3
```

and I have a method in which I want to get a Settings value based on some incoming integer value. Is there a way that I can concatenate the incoming integer and the name to make the assignment? I know I can just create a concat string, but is there a way to use that resulting string to get the *value* from the specified Setting?

In other words, just because I can do this

```
string combinedPath = "ClassLibrary.Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName" + (string)intValue;
```

The combined result is only a string, so I can't do this:

```
var mySettingsValue = combinedPath;
```

Is there a way to use that concatenated string to reference the object to which it points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to map strings to objects, you can use a [Dictionary<string, object>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-8.0) or similar data structure. Here’s an example:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

dict["ClassLibrary.Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName1"] = new MyObject();

string combinedPath = "ClassLibrary.Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName" + (string)intValue;
if (dict.ContainsKey(combinedPath))
{
    MyObject obj = dict[key] as MyObject;
    // Now you can use obj
}
```

(In C#, you cannot directly use a concatenated string to reference an object. This is because C# is a statically typed language, and variable names are resolved at compile time, not at runtime.)

Comment: Thanks, David.  That looks like it will be useful. In my case, I just found that as the Settings are a regular collection, I can just use the string directly, as in myDesiredValue = Properties.Settings.Default["SettingName"]; to get the value. I can plug any string into the index, which is what I was after.